# Are symbolic links in /usr/local/bin to scripts in users home directory a security risk?

Tags: linux, bash, security, symbolic-link

When I want a script (usually `bash` or `python`) to be executable from anywhere in my folder structure, I tend to put a symbolic link into `/usr/local/bin`. Thus, I don't have to recopy the script every time I make some changes.

I think that with this setup, somebody with access to my user's account will be able to change the script. If it was a multi-user system, this would probably be very bad. But since it is just a single-user desktop, there is no difference, because an attacker with access to the user account could easily execute anything she wants with user rights, no matter the symlinks to my scripts in `/usr/local/bin`.

The scripts do not need any extended permissions in order to execute correctly.

Anyway: Does this strategy pose a security risk on a single-user system?

Comment: Why didn't you put all those script in a directory (`~/bin/MyScript`) and you add that directory in your `PATH`?

Comment: The degree on which your approach increases the security risk to the system in question depends on information which you did not provide yet, namely whether or not those scripts have been granted additional permissions, e.g. will be executed with superuser rights.

Comment: @Hastur - I just didn't think of it, so thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Class_Stacker: The scripts have not been granted any additional permissions - is that even possible? As I understand the permissions depend on the user who executes the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are the only user who wants to access your scripts it would be better to just create a folder named "scripts" in your home folder and add it to your PATH.

Add this to your `~/.profile` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/scripts
```

You can keep different scripts in different folders (e.g. ~/pythonscripts/script_version1.py and ~/pythonscripts/script_version2.py) and a symbolic link to the newest version in ~/scripts

Answer (score -1):

If you are the only one executing your script and the set user-id bit is not set (chmod +s), there is no difference.

If the script is called by another user, your $HOME needs to be readable by that user if you use symlinks, which can have security implications especially if you choose to make your $HOME readable by everyone.
Also keep in mind that any process owned by your user can change the script and use it to gain the privileges of the calling user as mentioned by hastur.

Comment: If the symbolic link is owned by root you will execute the script as root. Not really a safe sleeping... You can be lossy in your not root user policy, a javascript on your browser is potentially able to change files owned by the user... I let you to finish this line of consideration... :) BTW I didn't downvote you, someone was faster :)

Comment: It doesn't matter who owns the symlink, it matters who calls the script/symlink.

Comment: If the script is to be called by root, I agree there are security implications. But if the script is called only by the user owning the file, it makes no difference.